# Can we give file address path instead of file name in latex for .bib file in ubuntu

Tags: bibliographies, texmaker, ubuntu

Can I make one `.bib` file and keep it in one location and add the file path to this location in all my papers for references.

```
\bibliography{/home/dell/Desktop/authors}
```

Is it allowed instead of `\bibliography{authors}`?

Comment: Why don't you try it out? (But I would put such a bib in the texmf-local or texmfhome tree.)

Comment: Put your bibliography (in Ubuntu) at `~/texmf/bibtex/bib/authors.bib` or at least put a symlink there to wherever you are keeping your "`authors.bib`" file.  Although using path names may happen to work, it is not recommended.

Comment: I tried it and it is working fine.........@jon why it is not recommended? Where it can create problem?

Comment: As you showed, it "can" work, but it is not very portable. On a different computer, you'd need to change the `.tex` file. The portable solution, and the solution that involves less typing is to put the `.bib` file in a location that is search automatically (or at least a link from there to wherever you're keeping the file). The reason it happens to work is it thinks the filename is "/home/dell/Desktop/authors.bib", but that's not really the filename....

Comment: Thanks @jon for the efforts and the replies. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have four research papers and I prepared one .bib file and kept it in one location and add the file path to this location in all my papers for references. For example,

```
\bibliography{/home/dell/Desktop/authors}
```

instead of

```
\bibliography{authors}
```

and its working perfectly alright.